# Why BindingAdapter must be static method?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, static-methods, android-databinding

I just learn how to use data binding on Android. And I want to ask why [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html) must be set to static method? If I can make it non-static method. What I must to do? I need to load my image into my own ImageLoader object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The BindingAdapter doesn't *have* to be static. It is just much easier to work with if it is static. If you must use an instance method, you can, but you must provide a way for the instance to be reached through the DataBindingComponent.

Let's imagine that you have an instance BindingAdapter:

```
public class ImageBindingAdapters {
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ImageBindingAdapters(ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        this.imageLoader = imageLoader;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("url")
    public void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        imageLoader.loadInto(imageView, url);
    }
}
```

First, whatever class contains the instance BindingAdapter must be provided as a method of the DataBindingComponent. It is a generated interface that you implement and the method is based on the name of the class:

```
public class MyComponent implements DataBindingComponent {
    @Override
    public ImageBindingAdapters getImageBindingAdapters() {
        //... whatever you do to create or retrieve the instance
        return imageBindingAdapter;
    }
}
```

Now, you have to provide the component during binding. For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    MyBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
            R.layout.my, new MyComponent());
    binding.setData(/* whatever */);
}
```

So, it is mostly used if you use dependency injection. You can also use `DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent()` if you don't need to change the component for each binding.